# Always enter emacs mode with ansi-term

Tags: evil, spacemacs, ansi-term

I have a freshly installed spacemacs installation and I want to make it so that I `ansi-term` is in emacs mode. However, I try to add

```
(add-to-list 'evil-emacs-state-modes 'term-mode)
```

to my `.spacemacs` in the `dotspacemacs/user-config` and/or `dotspacemacs/user-init` function and it has no effect.

Is there a canonical way to do this in spacemacs?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use this snippet in your `dotspacemacs/user-config` function:

```
(evil-set-initial-state 'term-mode 'emacs)
```

Comment: I assume you mean `dotspacemacs/user-config`? I have no `dospacemacs/user-configuration`.

Answer (score 2):

Disclaimer: I assume this is in no way related to Spacemacs.

The `evil-emacs-state-modes` variable is initialized with a list of modes to start in Emacs state.  This is a mishap as it makes it harder to customize it properly, any successful change to the variable will not take this value into account and Evil's code will not change it either because the variable is defined and initialized by then.  In your example, nothing happens as `add-to-list` does only do something if the variable has already been defined.  You can circumvent this by using a hook run after the package has been loaded up or with `eval-after-load`:

```
(eval-after-load 'evil-vars '(add-to-list 'evil-emacs-state-modes 'term-mode))
```

The official way of changing that list though is via `evil-set-initial-state`:

```
(eval-after-load 'evil-vars '(evil-set-initial-state 'term-mode 'emacs))
```

Comment: Great, this worked after putting it in the `dotspacemacs/user-config` (not `dotspacemacs/user-init` since I think spacemacs overrides the behaviour there)